# How can I make the display of the Hololense 2 working?

Tags: hololens

Problem: The display of the Hololense 2 is not turning on. The LEDS are working fine. I can still hear the turn-off sound.

I tried to follow the instructions to restart and forced restart the hololense still the display is not working. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-recovery

Does someone have similar difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

If restarting it isn't changing anything when you power cycle you should scroll further down the page and try reinstalling the OS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-recovery#hololens-2
Specifically you'll want to try do this: Turn it completely off then, Press and hold the **Volume Up and Power buttons** until the device reboots. Release the Power button, but continue to hold the Volume Up button until the third LED is lit.
After that then connect it to your PC and use Advanced Recovery Companion.

If after ARC finishes and reinstalls the OS and you still don't have a display you should contact support.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapid=e9391227-fa6d-927b-0fff-f96288631b8f